# Flutter app not comunicate to ip address network only on ios

Tags: flutter, dart, networking

the following code allows me to communicate in rest with a device when I connect to it, on Android everything works while on iOS it gives me the following error: how is this possible? how do I solve it? the ip is on local network

**Error**

```
errore chiamata 3:DioException [connection error]: The connection errored: Connection failed Error: SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: No route to host, errno = 65), address = 10.4.0.1, port = 3001
```

**flutter code:**

```
 var headers = {

          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        };

        var data = json.encode(map);

        var dio = Dio();
        var serverlink = await Storage.leggi("URL"); http://10.4.0.1:3000
        var response = await dio.request(

          serverlink + '/recipes/add',

          options: Options(

            method: 'POST',

            headers: headers,

          ),
          data: data,
        );

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          print(json.encode(response.data));
          sendError(json.encode(response.data));
        }
        else {
          sendError(response.statusMessage);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        sendError("errore chiamata 3:" + err.toString());
      }
      ret = "Ricetta inserita con successo";
```